# Array of duplicate elements remove buy using dictionaries?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

**by using only dictionaries to remove duplicate elements in array.

Comment: Please edit your question with the code you have tired, the input you have and the results desired so we may best assist you here.

Answer (score 0):

```
let x = [1,2,3,1,2]

let arr2= {}

for(let i = 0; i <x.length;i++){

    arr2 = Object.assign(arr2, {
        [x[i]]: x[i]
    })
}

console.log(Object.keys(arr2))
```